# oom-kill with enough (?) memory running julia program

Tags: ubuntu, memory, julia, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having trouble running a Julia program on Ubuntu on WSL2. It stops and just says `killed`. After running `sudo dmesg`, I get the following message:

```
oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/,task=julia,pid=1412,uid=1000
[ 1772.507795] Out of memory: Killed process 1412 (julia) total-vm:8780912kB, anon-rss:3566556kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:13772kB oom_score_adj:0
(
```

I checked the available free memory with `println("memory: ", Int(Base.Sys.free_memory()))` during runtime. It starts with about 1,2GB and right before it crashes has about 0.5GB left. The program is quite large and I can't really provide a MWE. My question is: Why is the oom-kill triggered if there is enough free memory?

Furthermore, the same program worked a few weeks ago. I reset it to the old commit and the only thing that changed was that I installed the CUDA toolkit. Is there any chance that this interferes with my program?

I am out of ideas and it would be awesome if someone has an idea or can point me in the right direction. Thank you :)

Comment: this is because WSL2 https://superuser.com/questions/1707758/wsl-2-does-not-have-all-memory-available-to-it